# how to do add action in route laravel 10

Tags: laravel-10

I want to use the method used in Laravel 5.8 as shown in the example below:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'panel.profile.index', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@index', 'title' => 'NAME ROUTE']);
```

I want to have access to the `title` through `Route::getRoutes()`.

If I want to use Laravel version 10, what should I do?

```
Route::get('/', [ProfileController::class, 'index', 'title' => 'TITLE ROUTE NAME'])->name("panel.profile.index");
```

result:

```
{#824 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Panel\CronController.php:107
  +"uri": "profile"
  +"methods": array:2 [▶]
  +"action": {#825 ▼
    +"middleware": array:3 [▶]
    +"uses": "App\Http\Controllers\Panel\Profile\ProfileController@index"
    +"controller": "App\Http\Controllers\Panel\Profile\ProfileController@index"
    +"namespace": "Panel\Profile"
    +"prefix": "/profile"
    +"where": []
    +"as": "panel.profile.index"
  }
  +"isFallback": false
  +"controller": null
  +"defaults": []
  +"wheres": []
  +"parameters": null
  +"parameterNames": null
  +"computedMiddleware": null
  +"compiled": null
}
```